# Groupby, Shift and Sum

Tags: python, pandas, shift

I have the following dataframe:

```
product    Week_Number       Sales
1               1              10
2               1              15
1               2              20
```

And I would like to groupby product and week number and create a column with the sales of the next week for that product:

```
product    Week_Number       Sales       next_week
1               1              10            20      
2               1              15             0
1               2              20             0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) :

```
#if not sure if sorted per 2 columns
df = df.sort_values(['product','Week_Number'])

#pandas 0.24+
df['next_week'] = df.groupby('product')['Sales'].shift(-1, fill_value=0)
#pandas below
#df['next_week'] = df.groupby('product')['Sales'].shift(-1).fillna(0, downcast='int')
print (df)
   product  Week_Number  Sales  next_week
0        1            1     10         20
1        2            1     15          0
2        1            2     20          0
```

If possible duplicates and need aggregate `sum` first in real data:

```
df = df.groupby(['product','Week_Number'], as_index=False)['Sales'].sum()
df['next_week'] = df.groupby('product')['Sales'].shift(-1).fillna(0, downcast='int')
print (df)
   product  Week_Number  Sales  next_week
0        1            1     10         20
1        1            2     20          0
2        2            1     15          0
```

Answer (score 0):

First sort the data
Then apply shift using tranform

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'product':[1,2,1],
                        'week_number':[1,1,2],
                        'sales':[10,15,20]})
df.sort_values(['product','week_number'],inplace=True)
df['next_week'] = df.groupby(['product'])['sales'].transform(pd.Series.shift,-1,fill_value=0)
print(df)
```

```
      product  week_number  sales  next_week
0        1            1     10         20
2        1            2     20          0
1        2            1     15          0
```